# uploadify button does not display upload button in IE

Tags: jquery, uploadify

i'm in big trouble while using jquery uploadify plugin. It works with google chrome and firefox but in IE 7/8 upload file button not displaying. Anyone have idea about this?
    i've latest flash player installed.

Comment: Their [demo](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/) work fine for me on IE8, so there is probably a problem with your implementation.

Comment: no, i don't think so because i downloaded latest uploadify few minutes ago and run on IE but same issue. No upload file flash button displaying.
Can u display your implemented code??

Comment: I used the demo link on their website.  http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Comment: i used this same but not displaying button. can u please explain me what could be the reason behind this? I reinstall my flash player. it is now updated and latest version. any suggestion?

Comment: I'm having the same problem; even the demo does not work. Could this be an IE10 issue? I am using uploadifive when IE9+ detected, but when I run IE8 developer mode it does not load. I know it used to work in IE9.

Comment: Did some more investigating, and if you are running IE10 in IE8/7/9 document standards (simulated user agent) this will not work. To test, you must run in a native IE9 (or lower) environment. IE10 appears to not be compatible with the flash version of this tool at all (even with messing around with the tweak recommendations to SWFObject). The uploadifive version works fine though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a uploadifive member, who posted on the old forum, a method to detect, hide , show either the upload'ifive' or the upload'ify' version to make this more cross browser compatible.

I can not contact him/her as the forum is shut down.

http://www.uploadify.com/forum/#/discussion/comment/16896

Is anyone skilled enough to make sense of this post by user "chopstick" and implement his code?

EDIT go to themeforest they have lots of alternatives that work from ie6 and up >